# Dockerize Multi Module Maven Project

Tags: maven, docker, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot multi-module Maven project and I want to make a container of each module project. If it is possible to do it, how do I make the Dockerfiles for each sub-module?

Comment: What all are your individual modules doing?? Are they different services.?? Generally you don't containerise any module. You have to containerise applications. So think from perspective of your applications to containerise.

Comment: Yes, they are different services. Should I make then multiple projects?

Comment: Yes, multiple projects would be preferred. Let's say you keep it as it is now and you change one of the modules and that change does not imply any change in the other two modules, now you have 2 new binaries / artifacts as a result of the multi-module setup where nothing changed, just because an unrelated change triggered a new build

Answer (score 0):

This article should help: http://iamsouveek.wordpress.com.
Similar to microservices, you can create dockerfiles for modules as well. Build each artifact(e.g. jar if using java)and define their relations using a docker-compose.yml

Comment: I tried using Dockerfile with the jar, but I get "Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set", even though it works on the host.

Comment: It seems there is some property missing in your configuration. Please see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190331/hibernateexception-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null-when-hiberna) helps