# Docker - multi stage build with multi-module Maven project

Tags: java, docker, maven, caching, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a Maven Project that has a root `pom.xml` file that has multiple sub-folders as modules and dependencies.

It looks something like this:

```
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
    ...
    ...
```

Each module/dependency generates its own `JAR` file.

I'm using the Maven Dependency Plugin to unpack my final `JAR` to classes and dependencies folders separately.

So my `Dockerfile` has something like this in it:

```
COPY ${FOLDER}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${FOLDER}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${FOLDER}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
```

The dependencies are in `/app/lib`, but since my sub-folders (modules) are some of those dependencies, that `COPY` layer never gets cached since those sub-folders are where i change my code.
(In that `/app/lib` folder there's a mix of modules dependencies and 3rd party dependencies).

Is there any way i can cache all other dependencies (3rd party) other than those modules? 
Or is it not possible since in the end they're all dependencies?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44087697/400544